# Java: popen()-like function?

Tags: java, popen

This is in the context of a local [Processing](http://processing.org) program.  I would like to run an external program to get some data.  Is there a popen() or equivalent function I can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
```

Then you can read and write the data using the [`Process`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) streams.

Answer (score 5):

JDK5 introduced [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for more control over the process generation.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start()
```

Be aware of the fact, that internally forkAndExec is invoked, and fork 'makes a copy of the entire parents address space', so that even a little command can lead to OutOfMemoryErrors, when the parent process has big amount of memory space acquired.

[see here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/subprocess-136439.html)

Comment: Could you add a link to ProcessBuilder documentation?

Answer (score 1):

A close friend of `popen()` is to make a named pipe as input and/or output, like in UNIX:

```
mknod /tmp/mypipe.12345 p ; sort -o /tmp/mypipe.12345 /tmp/mypipe.12345 &
```

Then open `/tmp/mypipe.12345`, write, close, open `/tmp/mypipe.12345`, read, close. Since a sort cannot write anything until `EOF` on input, the output open will occur after the input close. The `popen()` call cannot do this!

For simpler scenarios, the named pipe can just be read or written.

Of course, you still need to spin it off, as in a `system(...)` call.

You want to remove the named pipe when you are done.  On some UNIX systems, `/tmp` is cleared upon reboot.

`/tmp` is shared so name collisions are quite possible.  You can generate a partly random pipe file name (numeric part of `/tmp/mypipe.12345`) in **Java** to generally prevent this.  In some systems, **Bash** creates named pipes in `/var/tmp` for every `<(...)` or `>(...)` use.  Unfortunately, it is a bit of a challenge to determine when they can be removed without effect (fuser?)!