# How to access files in SVN using java

Tags: java, svn

I need help from you, i want open a file from SVN using java code, can any one tell me the flow of accessing the files, or can any one send me sample code for that one.

Can any one send me example code for accessing svn through HTML using java.

Comment: You can use e.g. SVNKit. http://wiki.svnkit.com/Managing_A_Working_Copy

Comment: @mich Why don't you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

You need to look at [SVNKIT, Subversion for Java](http://svnkit.com/). From there:

It supports

- Repository access over http(s), svn, svn(+ssh) and file protocols.
- Working copy operations - all are supported.
- Repository administration: create, load, dump and replay operations.
- Additionally to its own API, SVNKit implements JavaHL API.
- SVNKit is reported to work on Windows, OSX, Linux, BSD and OpenVMS.
- SVNKit does not require native binaries, it works out of the box.
- Native Subversion configuration files are used by default.
- Java Subversion command line client is part of SVNKit.
- Latest SVNKit supports Subversion 1.6.5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm access over the http means what i'm doing, had finished authendication part, i couldn't access the files after login.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not use for my projects, It seems like following library is worth to look at.
http://svnkit.com/

Answer (score 1):

A simple way could be to run an `svn` command from Java. For instance you could run the command

```
 svn cat yourfile.txt > /tmp/yourtemporaryplace.txt
```

then have Java read the `/tmp/yourtemporaryplace.txt`.  Even better, read from the process running `svn cat yourfile.txt` like in [this question on java popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887658/java-popen-like-function)

You could also use a SVN client java library like [svnkit](http://svnkit.com/)

(PS I don't code in Java usually, just googled for you)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this at work, and are not working on an open source project, I would stray away from SVNKit. They call themselves open source, but will charge you if you use SVNKit for [commercial purposes](https://svnkit.com/licensing.html).

Another good option is [Apache Maven SCM](https://maven.apache.org/scm/)(Source Code Manager). The docs are a little spotty, but it is truly open source. Here's a link to their page with some [SVN examples](https://maven.apache.org/scm/guide/usage.html).

Comment: But Maven SCM is for reaching repo through the maven command, or?
You can not use it, to connect to a repository from your JAVA app, and read file content, or?