# Intercept output from a running Java program

Tags: java

Is it possible to grab / intercept the output from an already running Java program?

This is my situation: I'm running a program which takes some hours to finish. So I start it and let the computer do it's work. I can login on the computer running the program with SSH and see the it running with **ps**, but I would like to intercept the output which is written to the console.

Is there any way to do this?

Do I need to provide extra information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start the application in a `screen` session, detach from the session and later you can ssh in and reattach to see the progress.
Here's some information on [using screen](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/34).

Another option is to redirect the standard ouput and standard error to a file, and use something like `tail` to view its content. example: `my_program &> /tmp/output`

Ok, I just realized I was a bit offtopic, because I handled the cases where you had to think ahead. Now, if tou want to get it from a running process you can use `gdb`.

```
gdb -p process_id
(gdb) p close(1)
$1 = 0
(gdb) p creat(“/tmp/output″, 0600)
$2 = 1
(gdb) q
```

This will put the output to `/tmp/output` and again, you can use `tail` to see it interactively.

Comment: +1 for mentioning redirecting to file and using `tail` to view.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is it also possible to 'detach' the new listener? I also want to note you have to do this as **root** user.

Comment: Is it possible to explain a little what these gdb commands do? I already found this article, but it doesn't explain each command: [link](http://blog.tridgell.net/?p=4)

Comment: To me, tail a log file is the best solution, using tail -f <filename>, however, note that in Linux you could attach a running program to & from user front & background. Just remember to get the process id. As Uku said, Screen & Tail would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should capture it's standard input, output, and error streams. Check out `$ man popen` or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887658/java-popen-like-function).

EDIT: For an already running process, see if you can attach a basic debugger to the process and duplicate the input and output streams as per above.